# Async Await API call inside componentDidMount() is suddenly failing/exceeding timeout? React-Native. Redux. Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, async-await, thunk

Async call inside componentDidMount is exceeding timeout and failing.

The api call itself is not using redux, but the data retrieved is.

Is this an instance where I would need to use Redux Thunk?
How would Thunk be applied to the initial get call?

Can't seem to get passed the initial await call.

**Component.tsx**

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    const { resetItems, loadItems } = this.props;
    try {
      const stuff: Stuff[] | null = await stuffService.getItems();
      if (stuff && stuff.length > 0) {
        loadItems(stuff);
      } else {
        resetItems();
      }
    } catch {}
  }
```

**stuffService.tsx**

```
function getItems(): Promise<Stuff[] | null> {
  return request({
    url: "Items",
    method: "GET",
  });
}
```

**index.ts**

```
export function loadItems(stuff: Stuff[]): ActionTypes {
  return {
    type: "LOAD_ITEMS",
    stuff,
  };
}

export function resetThings(): ActionTypes {
  return {
    type: "RESET_ITEMS",
  };
}
```

Things I've tried:
Moving the call outside of componentDidMount.
Using other life cycle methods.
Using Thunk on the loadItems();

```
export function loadItemsAsync(stuff: Stuff[]) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(loadItems(stuff));
    }, 9000);
  };
}
```

Comment: Don't worry about thunks unless you want to move the api request logic into a dispatched action. Anyway, about the API call - does this every succeed? Can you run a request with CURL, etc. outside of React Native?

Comment: Looks like it is exceeding the timeout. Too much data being sent back at the moment. Thanks for your response.